# Loading views in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Hey guys, I'm having an issue with loading multiple views in codeigiter.

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('body-view', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

The code above will allow me to load views right after each other on other servers I have worked on. For some reason, my server will only ouput one of these views at a time. I have been using codeigniter for a few years now, so I know that this is valid syntax.

Could it be an output issue with my servers configuration? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that all views load completely without error when called individually?

Comment: I have checked each idividual view

Comment: You must have problem with your codeiginiter core files.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. Some how  i guess the package of codeigniter must have gotten corrupted. I just reconfigured codeigniter all over again with a fresh downloaded version and my code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this approach

```
$view = $this->load->view('header',array(),TRUE);
$view .= $this->load->view('body-view', $data , TRUE );
$view .= $this->load->view('footer',array(),TRUE);

echo $view;
```

Also check your html syntex it might be causing problem when loading multiple views. Please validate your html and try again.

Comment: Why do you think that this is different of what he was trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
I guess you are not passing true parameter while passing view file.
please refer bellow tricks:
$output  = $this->load->view('your_view', 'your_data', true);
$output .= $this->load->view('your_other_view', 'your_other_data', true);
$output .= $this->load->view('your_last_view', 'your_last_data', true);
$this->output->set_output($output);

**Second Method, you can be passing view with data like :**
$data['header']  = $this->load->view('your_header_view_file_name', true);
$data['footer']  = $this->load->view('your_footer_view_file_name', true);
$data['your_necessary_data'] = $your variables ;
$data['your_necessary_data2'] = $your variables ;    
$this->load->view('blogview',$data);
```